# After Successful twitter sharing call back not coming to my app

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

I am using the following code for twitter sharing. Here i am checking if twitter native app installed in the device then i am opening the native app otherwise i am opening the webView for twitter sharing. Using the following code  i am able to do twitter sharing, But the problem is After successful sharing the call back is not coming to my app, It is going to twitter app.

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://post?message=hello%20world"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
    } else {
        //       <a href="twitter://tweet?text=I share this on Twitter from a website">Share this on Twitter</a>
        GenericWebViewController *gwvController=[[GenericWebViewController alloc] init];
        [gwvController loadWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=www.google.com&text=I%20am%20eating%20branston%20pickel%20right%20now&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9127808%2Fhow-do-you-include-hashtags-within-twitter-share-link-text"] navBarTitle:@"Twitter"];
        UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];
        [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:gwvController animated:YES];
        //WI-542:Showing the navigation bar in WebView when user user navigate from deal details.
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    }
```

How can i come back to my app after successful sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not! Once you launch an external application, you can not go back to your application, unless the external application is specifically done this way (using a "callback" arg for instance), but very few "big name" (twitter, facebook,...) works this way

If you want to use Twitter and still don't exit from your app, use the Twitter frame work (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html )

It's a little bit more complex, but you'll gain the benefit of remaining in your app.